# Python Changing Array Values in While Loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I am working on a project where I have the following while loop:

```
i = 0 
while i <= length:
    u[:,i] = u[:,i] - u_val
    y[:,i] = y[:,i] - y_val
    i = i + 1
```

The goal is to subtract u_val and y_val from their respective arrays along the entire length of each array. Both y and u have a same length, with u having a dimension of 2 and y a dimension of 1.

u and y are coming from an array "data" and are defined by:

```
u = data[1:1+ni]
y = data[1+ni:1+ni+no]
```

u_val and y_val are also coming from "data" and are defined by:

```
u_ss = data[1:1+ni,0]
y_ss = data[1+ni:1+ni+no,0]
```

u_val = array([0.04,550000.0]) and y_val = array([400.153])

The first loop works with the values being subtracted from the first values of each array, but then python is setting u_val = array([0.,0.]) and y_val = array([0.]). So the loop continues to run but zero is now being subtracted from everything. I have looked at the variable explorer and for some reason the loop changes the original entries on the array "data" to zero as well. Why would the loop be doing this?

I have restarted several times and I have tried it as a for loop as well. I cannot figure out what in the loop is triggering the change in the original array. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please simply add the full code (I guess relatively short) so the world willing to help has not to e.g. guess what `length` might have for a value and how to try that snippet on a different machine at hand ;-)

Comment: I added the [tag:numpy] tag to your question because I assume you are using numpy, if not then please specify what kind of arrays you are using in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data[1:1+ni,0]` is a `view` of data.  So is `data[1:1+ni]` (which also can be expressed as `data[1:1+ni, :]`).  If you change an element of one view (as in `u[:,i] = u[:,i] - u_val`), you change the corresponding element in `data`, and in any other view that contains that element.  So without sorting out all the slicing ranges, I can see where this calculation could end up changing the value(s) of `u_val`.

You may need to make some copies, such as

```
u_val = data[1:1+ni,0].copy()
```

to isolate `u_val` from changes in `u` (and `data`).

Understanding copies and views is fundamental to working with `numpy`.

Can't

```
i = 0 
while i <= length:
    u[:,i] = u[:,i] - u_val
    y[:,i] = y[:,i] - y_val
    i = i + 1
```

be replaced by:

```
u -= u_val[:,None]
y -= y_val[:,None]
```

I added the `None` to expand the dimension of `u_val` so it can broadcast against 2d `u`.  If that doesn't work, review the shapes of `u` and `u_val`, etc.